# $E[E[X|Y]|X]$ please help

Tags: probability, conditional-expectation

What is $E[E[X|Y]|X]$? Is it just $X$? Any hint?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: Well, $E[X|Y]$ is a function of $Y$ ... Feels weird to then add the information about $X$ to this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will depend on how $X$ and $Y$ are related.

Considering the extremes, if $X=Y$ (or more generally, $\sigma(X) = \sigma(Y)$), then $$E\Big[E[X|Y]\Big|X\Big] = E\Big[E[X|X]\Big|X\Big] = E\Big[X\Big|X\Big] = X$$
while if $X,Y$ are independent $$E\Big[E[X|Y]\Big|X\Big] = E\Big[E[X]\Big|X\Big] = E\Big[X\Big]$$

Comment: Hi, thank you very much for the help. What if they are have some correlation that isn't 0 or 1 (or -1)?

Comment: @BrekeenO First, note that the correlation doesn't actually contain the right information to help evaluate this (except, I believe, in the very restricted case of $\pm 1$).  I actually don't know if there is _any_ single measure that would help. ------- In any case, you most likely would need to work with an example to evaluate it, as the best we can do in general is give some properties the result would have.